# How to convert javascript date time zone offset values to duration string format?

Tags: javascript, timezone

In javascript, I want to get the timezone value in the format like `"-04:00"`. But I want to start from `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`. I have this so far

```
function getTimeZoneOffset() {
    //var t = new Date().toString().match(/[-\+]\d{4}/)[0];
    //return t.substring(0,3) + ":" + t.substr(3);
    var g = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / -60;
    if (g > -10 && g < 0) g = g.toString().replace("-", "-0");
    else if (g === 0) g = "00";
    else if (g > 0 && g < 10) g = "+0" + g;
    g += ":00";
    return g;
}
```

But it doesn't work when dealing with fractions or timezones where it is like `xx:30`. How can this be improved?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest changing your code to be slightly more readable.

```js
var total_minutes = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / -1;
```

then, you can get the hours by flooring the quotient, as you've already done.

```js
var hours = (total_minutes / 60);
// negative
```

We want the remainder of the hour calculation, so we add:

```js
var minutes = (-1 * total_minutes) % 60
```

Then format it using your method above you will need to tinker it. Let me know if you need help with that.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you want:

```js
function formatOffsetToHhMm (offsetInMins) {
      var negative=offsetInMins<0?"-":"";
      var positiveMins= Math.abs(offsetInMins);
    
      var hours   = Math.floor(positiveMins/ 60);
      var mins = Math.floor((positiveMins- ((hours * 3600)) / 60));
      if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
      if (mins < 10) {mins = "0"+mins;}
   
      return negative+hours+':'+mins;
    }
 
  var myLocalOffset=new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  
  console.log(`local offset ${myLocalOffset}: ${formatOffsetToHhMm(myLocalOffset)}`);
 
  console.log(`pass 30 to function:   ${formatOffsetToHhMm(30)}`);
  
  console.log(`pass -30 to function: ${formatOffsetToHhMm(-30)}`);
   
  console.log(`pass 0  to function:   ${formatOffsetToHhMm(0)}`);
```